# Abort TFDConnection in OnLogin() event?

Tags: c++builder, firedac

I have my own password handler for the `OnLogin` event of a `TFDConnection` object.   The return value of that handler is `void` so I can't tell it to abort the connection and optionally exit the program.

I would guess I would then have to `throw` something in some form to tell it to abort, but I didn't see anything in the documentation.

What is the proper way to abort the attempt to connect in `OnLogin` when the password dialog has a `Cancel` button?   I'd like to just exit the application if it fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would guess I would then have to throw something in some form to tell it to abort, but I didn't see anything in the documentation.

Your guess is correct.  Simply `throw` any exception you want.

`TFDConnection`'s default behavior when its own [`LoginDialog`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDConnection.LoginDialog) is canceled is to call the [`FDException()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.FDException) function to throw an [`EFDException`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDException) exception that has its [`FDCode`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDException.FDCode) property set to `er_FD_ClntDbLoginAborted`.

> I'd like to just exit the application if it fails as well.

Before exiting your `OnLogin` handler, you can call `Application->Terminate()` (or `Application->MainForm->Close()`).  Or, whatever code is connecting the `TFDConnection` can `catch` the exception you `throw`, and then it can call `Terminate()` (or `Close()`), as demonstrated in the documentation:

[Establishing Connection (FireDAC) : Handling Connection Errors](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Establishing_Connection_(FireDAC)#Handling_Connection_Errors)